# How do you measure the likelihood of having a run?

Tags: correlation, autocorrelation

I have some data that has runs of 0s with some 1s thrown in. For example:

```
000000000100000000010000000000000000000111111100000000
```

However, the 1s are much more sparse.

I want to calculate a measure of how "runny" the data is.  What I mean by this is I want to have a low value if my data only has single 1s interspersed with 0s. But if there are lots of runs of 1s or long runs of 1s I want a high value.

What is a good way to measure this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the runs test:

Let N be the number of observations, with $N_+$ and $N_-$ the 1's and 0's. Then, if the null is true, the number of runs (of any length) should be normally distributed with :

$\mu = \frac{N_+N_-}{N}+ \frac{1}{2}$

and

$\sigma^2 = \frac{(\mu - 1)(\mu-2)}{N-1}$

you can then test this with standard tables or functions.

Comment: I don't care about runs of 0s, I only want to look for how runny the 1s are. So if all the data is 0s I don't want a high "run" value.

Comment: How does this question even fit into a hypothesis testing setting, Peter?  Dan, the runs of zeros and ones are intimately connected: for instance, their counts can differ by at most one. So don't reject out of hand those measures that account for both types of runs--they still might do what you need.

Comment: OK, i now see that my response doesn't answer the question, but I will leave it as it has comments appended.

Comment: @dan as the 1s get more 'runny', so do the 0's; you can't really avoid measuring both. The total number of runs of 1s and 0s can differ by *at most 1* from double the number of runs of 1s.

Answer (score 1):

While I think @PeterFlom's answer is better than you realize, there's a test for the number of runs of one kind; the number of runs of "1"s has a hypergeometric distribution.

If $n_1$ is the number of 1's and $n_0$ is the number of 0's and $n = n_0+n_1$, and $G$ is the number of runs of 1s, then assuming that $n_1$ is at least 1:

$G$ ranges between $1$ and $\min(n_1, n_0+1)$  (in your case, that upper bound will probably always be $n_1$).

$E(G)=\frac{n_1(n_0+1)}{n}$

$Var(G)=\frac{n_1 n_0(n_1-1)(n_0+1)}{n^2(n-1)}$

$P(G=g) = \frac{\binom{n_1-1}{g-1}\binom{n_0+1}{g}}{\binom{n_1+n_0}{n_1}}$

You could construct various measures of 'lumpiness' of 1's from those measures.

As I point out in my comment on Peter Flom's answer, this is closely related to the more usual runs test he discusses.

e.g. 1: If you take an index like this: $R = \frac{G-E(G)}{n_1-E(G)}$ ($R$ for 'runs index', not anything to do with correlation) then $R$ will be a number that takes the value 1 when the number of runs is at a maximum (one run for every '1'), which takes the value 0 when the number of runs reflects 'random' lumpiness, and is negative when the 1's are lumpier than random. If there's exactly one run of '1's, it attains its minimum value, but that value can't quite reach -1.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a simple counting approach for your measure? Start your count at zero. For every isolated "1" you add 1 to your count. For every instance of "11" you add two to the count. A triple "111" will add four to the count, and so on. If you don't like this weighting scheme, then create one more in line with how you want to balance a lot of isolated ones versus a longer streak.

If you need to compare data streams of different lengths, then you will need to make an adjustment for the length of each data pattern.